# How can I create Summary Tables with a modified regression?

Tags: r, latex, summary, stargazer, robustness

I want to export the summary() function of several regressions into a summary table. Normally I use stargaze.

The problem is: I calculated Heteroskedasticity Robust Standard errors which are shown by using a special summary function (e.g. "summary(fit5, robust=TRUE)") - but how can I export the result of this summary table into an export table?
Thank you very much for your help!

Nothing worked so far. Until now I used the export type text and overwrote the values...

Comment: Welcome to stack. Could you share a reproducible data, along with the code you've tried, and show us how you want the data to look.

Comment: Hi Jim, 
thank you for your reply.

That's some sample code using cars data:
fit <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)

summary(fit)
summary(fit, robust=TRUE)

I used the Guide from this side:
https://economictheoryblog.com/2016/08/08/robust-standard-errors-in-r/

Usually I would create a summary table by
stargazer(fit, fit1, fit1, title="Regression Results",
          align=TRUE, dep.var.labels=c("depVar"),
          covariate.labels=c("label1", "label2", "and so on"),

Answer (score 0):

`tidy` from the `broom` package will give you a tibble with your regression coefficients:

```
library(broom)

fit <-lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)

summary(fit) %>%
  tidy()

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)   -17.6      6.76      -2.60 1.23e- 2
2 speed           3.93     0.416      9.46 1.49e-12
```

Comment: Hi Paul,

thank you for your answer!

Unfortunately it does not solve my problem. I try to restate it:
I have several regressions which I want to export into one summary statistics, e. g. like described here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf

But unfortunately I don't need the standard summary(my_reg) but the summary(my_reg, robust=TRUE) - I need to show the Heteroskedasticity Robust Standard Errors in my output table which I import into Latex

Answer (score 0):

For those of you interested in the answer!
I found this tutorial: 
https://economictheoryblog.com/2018/05/18/cluster-robust-standard-errors-in-stargazer/

Nevertheless, thanks to all of you who tried to help!

Comment: Can you include the relevant information directly in your answer? The idea is that answers on stackoverflow should be self-contained to make sure they will still be helpful in case the external link is no longer reachable.